# Uniswap V1 Factory contract with ethers.js not working

Tags: uniswap, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, web3-providers, decentralized-exchange

I have tried the following code to get exchange address of DAI(0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F). But it's giving some strange error. Any idea what's going wrong? (I have verified the contract address and ABI)

Code:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(my_infura_url)

const UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI = [{ "name": "NewExchange", "inputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "token", "indexed": true }, { "type": "address", "name": "exchange", "indexed": true }], "anonymous": false, "type": "event" }, { "name": "initializeFactory", "outputs": [], "inputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "template" }], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 35725 }, { "name": "createExchange", "outputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "out" }], "inputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "token" }], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 187911 }, { "name": "getExchange", "outputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "out" }], "inputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "token" }], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 715 }, { "name": "getToken", "outputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "out" }], "inputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "exchange" }], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 745 }, { "name": "getTokenWithId", "outputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "out" }], "inputs": [{ "type": "uint256", "name": "token_id" }], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 736 }, { "name": "exchangeTemplate", "outputs": [{ "type": "address", "name": "out" }], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 633 }, { "name": "tokenCount", "outputs": [{ "type": "uint256", "name": "out" }], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 663 }]
const UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0xc0a47dFe034B400B47bDaD5FecDa2621de6c4d95'
const uniswapFactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS, UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI, provider)

const main = async () => {
    const exchangeAddress = await uniswapFactoryContract.getExchange("0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F")
    console.log(exchangeAddress)
}

main()
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:199
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: missing revert data in call exception (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":44,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"out of gas\"}}","error":{"code":-32000},"requestBody":"{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x5b63\",\"to\":\"0xc0a47dfe034b400b47bdad5fecda2621de6c4d95\",\"data\":\"0x06f2bf620000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":44,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}","requestMethod":"POST","url":"https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/b4e8a43f00d34e7590cef3b3eb8c5b82"}, data="0x", code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.5.3)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:199:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:208:20)
    at checkError (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:76:16)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:659:47)
    at step (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'missing revert data in call exception',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  error: Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":44,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"out of gas\"}}", error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_call\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x5b63\",\"to\":\"0xc0a47dfe034b400b47bdad5fecda2621de6c4d95\",\"data\":\"0x06f2bf620000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f\"},\"latest\"],\"id\":44,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/b4e8a43f00d34e7590cef3b3eb8c5b82", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.5.1)
      at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:199:21)
      at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:208:20)
      at C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:301:32
      at step (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
      at Object.next (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
      at fulfilled (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    reason: 'processing response error',
    code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
    body: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":44,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"out of gas"}}',
    error: Error: out of gas
        at getResult (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:142:21)
        at processJsonFunc (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:344:22)
        at C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:276:46
        at step (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:33:23)
        at Object.next (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:14:53)
        at fulfilled (C:\Users\rssav\node_modules\@ethersproject\web\lib\index.js:5:58)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
      code: -32000,
      data: undefined
    },
    requestBody: '{"method":"eth_call","params":[{"gas":"0x5b63","to":"0xc0a47dfe034b400b47bdad5fecda2621de6c4d95","data":"0x06f2bf620000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f"},"latest"],"id":44,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
    requestMethod: 'POST',
    url: my_infura_url
  },
  data: '0x'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const abi = [
    "function getExchange(address token) view returns (address)"
];
```

Modify your ABI to above code. I think that there is something wrong with json ABI you provided

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked.
I copied the ABI from etherscan(previously). From where do I get the ABI in the format you shared?

Comment: You can refer to Human-readable ABI from Ethers.js docs https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/formats/#abi-formats--human-readable-abi

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `out of gas`, if you copied your ABI from Uniswap docs, some functions have a gas definition as per below:

```
{
  name: "getExchange",
  outputs: [{ type: "address", name: "out" }],
  inputs: [{ type: "address", name: "token" }],
  constant: true,
  payable: false,
  type: "function",
  gas: "715",
}
```

Just remove the gas property.